# Define global values in Traceur on the fly compilation

Tags: javascript, traceur

I am trying traceur hello world example from their [Getting Started](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Getting-Started) page. Here's my code.

```
<script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/traceur.js"></script>
<script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/bin/BrowserSystem.js"></script>
<script src="https://google.github.io/traceur-compiler/src/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="module">
  import 'main.js';
</script>
```

And main.js has this:

```
window.a = 10;
function foo() {}
```

Now when I check value of a in console, it shows correctly But `foo` is undefined. I understand what's happening here, the `main.js` file is not being executed in global scope so `function` declarations don't register for global scope either.

I would like to be able to declare global classes and functions from within included files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can get around that with a simple

```
window.foo = function() {}
```